# Reputation Graph X Axis Bug in Edge and IE

Tags: bug, profile-page, reputation-graph

The small reputation graph on the profile page is broken in Edge and IE:

[image]

While in Chrome it looks like this:

[image]

Firefox also shows it correctly. I have not tested Safari.

I know the Edge rendering engine is going to go away at some point, so this issue will disappear in the long run, but it'd be nice if Stack Exchange worked on all browsers, not just the main ones.

Seeing as you are redesigning the profile page, seems like an ideal time to fix it.

Tested versions: Chrome 71.0.3578.98, Firefox 64.0, Edge 44.17763.1.0, IE 11.195.17763.0, all on Windows 10 1809 (17763).

Comment: Cross-site dupe on Meta.SO: [X-axis labels for the reputation graph are collapsed in Edge](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/375164/4642212).

Comment: IE is no longer supported: [Which browsers are officially supported, and what else do I need?](/q/56161/289905). The browsers that are all support `justify-content: space-evenly;`.

Answer (score 5):

It seems the CSS property `justify-content` is not working for Edge and IE. It was already [reported](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/platform/issues/15947692/) in the Microsoft developer forum. The same property is working as expected in Chrome and Firefox.

In the profile page for the section, the `<ul>` tag has the class `jc-space-evenly` and it has the CSS property of `justify-content: space-evenly` that caused the alignment issue.

The style class:

```
.jc-space-evenly {
    justify-content: space-evenly !important;
}
```

Screenshot for reference:

> [image: Edge]